# Windows Media Player in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I would like Access to "automatically" play a song whenever a combo box is updated.  I want that song to change depending on the contents of the combo box.  Unfortunately the below code returns:

```
Constant expression required
```

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
Private Sub cboCustomerID_AfterUpdate()
txtSongFile = Me.cboCustomerID.Column(2)
Me.Refresh
Const conMEDIA_FILE_TO_OPEN As String = Me.txtSongFile

Me![WindowsMediaPlayer1].openPlayer (conMEDIA_FILE_TO_OPEN)

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mentioned is a compile error, not a run time error.  It is caused by this line:

```vb
Const conMEDIA_FILE_TO_OPEN As String = Me.txtSongFile
```

The reason is that the VBA rule for what you can use on the right side of the `=` sign is quite restrictive.  This is what Access' online help says:

*"Literal, other constant, or any combination that includes all arithmetic or logical operators except Is."*

But you should be able to use a variable instead:

```vb
Dim strMEDIA_FILE_TO_OPEN As String
strMEDIA_FILE_TO_OPEN = Me.txtSongFile
```

Comment: Any recommendations for a not-too-complicated way to get WMP to open (and play) the filename from the combo??

Comment: I just updated the answer to suggest variable instead of constant.  Does that work with the rest of your code?